# Can a CL-term have multiple fixed points?

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

Given a CL term $E$, can there exist multiple non-equivalent fixed points for $E$?

I think: any fixed point of $E$ can be expressed as $Y(E)$, this expression cannot reduce to multiple non-equivalent forms, due to confluence. So, I think that any CL term can have only 1 fixed point.

Is my logic correct? All ideas regarding this problem are welcome.

**Edit:**

Realized just now, the identity combinator is a CL term with multiple non-equivalent fixed points. But then, if we consider the term $Y(I)$, this must have multiple non-equivalent forms, corresponding to the multiple fixed points of $I$. But how is that justifiable under confluence?

**Edit 2:**

$Y(I)$ is nothing but the omega combinator. I think I have got it now. Even when a CL term has multiple fixed points, applying that CL term to Y gives us only one possible fixed point. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

This may be useful to construct (partial) answers to your question:
In general, there are infinitely many non-β-equivalent fixed-point combinators in λ-calculus. Consider
$$ \delta := λy.λx.x(yx) =_β \mathsf{SI}, $$
then the terms $Y_n$ defined by
$$ Y_0 := Y \qquad Y_{n+1} := Y_n \delta $$
are fixed points combinators, and $Y_i \neq_β Y_j$.

This is called the *Böhm-van der Mey sequence*. What I know about it comes from Barendregt and Manzonetto ([2022](https://www.collegepublications.co.uk/logic/mlf/?00035)), who cite Klop ([2007](http://www.cs.ru.nl/barendregt60/essays/klop/art16_klop.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks for your help.